# Self-referencing JSON with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-rest

## Self-referencing JSON with Spring Data REST

In a [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) data model with [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html), how can we export and import data to self-referencing JSON without creating a parallel entities or DTOs?

For example, a self-referencing JSON using [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) for a simple music manager might look like:

```
{ "id" : 1,
  "albums" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "Kind Of Blue",
    "artist" : "$..artists[?(@.id=1)]",
    "tracks" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "title" : "So What",
      "duration" : "PT9M5S",
      "musicians" : [ {
        "musician" : "$..artists[?(@.id=1)]",
      }, {
        "musician" : "$..artists[?(@.id=2)]",
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : 3,
      "title" : "Blue in Green",
      "duration" : "PT5M29S",
      "musicians" : [ {
        "musician" : "$..artists[?(@.id=1)]",
      }, {
        "musician" : "$..artists[?(@.id=2)]",
      } ]
    } ]
  } ],
  "artists" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "Miles",
    "lastName" : "Davis",
    "birthDate" : "1926-05-26"
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "firstName" : "Bill",
    "lastName" : "Evans",
    "birthDate" : "1929-09-16"
  } ]
}
```

How can we create the import and export functionality for this representation while retaining the Spring Data REST HATEOAS functionality? The `musicians` container in an export/import has an array of string JSONPath expressions and in the REST APIs the `musicians` is an array of `Person` objects (see below) -- so how can Jackson be configured to select the correct serializer and deserializer the export and import operations?

### Details: music manager example

Here's a Spring Boot 1.5, Spring Data Rest, Lombok, and Jackson implementation ([GitHub](https://github.com/JanStureNielsen/so-music/edit/master/README.md)).

**Music**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Music {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Album> albums;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Person> artists;
}
```

**Album**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Person artist;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Track> tracks;
}
```

**Track**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Track {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyDurationSerializer.class)
    private Duration duration;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Person> musicians;

    public Track(String title, String duration, List<Person> musicians) {
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = Duration.parse(duration);
        this.musicians = musicians;
    }
}
```

**Person**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @JsonSerialize(using = MyLocalDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String birthDate) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = LocalDate.parse(birthDate);
    }
}
```

**MyDurationSerializer**

```
public class MyDurationSerializer extends StdSerializer<Duration> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected MyDurationSerializer() {
        super(Duration.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Duration value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

**MyLocalDateSerializer**

```
public class MyLocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

    protected MyLocalDateSerializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(value.format(FORMATTER));
    }
}
```

#### Spring Data REST HATEOAS representation

`curl http://localhost:4000/albums/1/tracks`

```
{ "id" : 1,
  "albums" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "title" : "Kind Of Blue",
    "artist" : "@{
      "id" : 1,
      "firstName" : "Miles",
      "lastName" : "Davis",
      "birthDate" : "1926-05-26"
    },
    "tracks" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "title" : "So What",
      "duration" : "PT9M5S",
      "musicians" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "Miles",
    "lastName" : "Davis",
    "birthDate" : "1926-05-26"
      }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "firstName" : "Bill",
    "lastName" : "Evans",
    "birthDate" : "1929-09-16"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id" : 3,
      "title" : "Blue in Green",
      "duration" : "PT5M29S",
      "musicians" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "Miles",
    "lastName" : "Davis",
    "birthDate" : "1926-05-26"
      }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "firstName" : "Bill",
    "lastName" : "Evans",
    "birthDate" : "1929-09-16"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ],
  "artists" : [ {
    "id" : 15,
    "firstName" : "Miles",
    "lastName" : "Davis",
    "birthDate" : "1926-05-26"
  }, {
    "id" : 16,
    "firstName" : "Bill",
    "lastName" : "Evans",
    "birthDate" : "1929-09-16"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking however if you expose the Musicians repo also as a RestResource then it will generate links rather than in-lining the data in the tracks response.